# Lazy download images into gridView

Tags: android, json, gridview, lazy-loading

In my application I need to download a lot of pictures from urls and display them in a gridView. (It can be between 1-200 pictures). I don't want to download all pictures at once. I read about lazy downloading and my question is: Can i get only one part of the Json, download the pictures in a different thread, **and only if the user scroll down** the gridView, I will continue to the other parts of the Json, and so on?

Edit: Hi again. I want to implement multi select in this gridView and i'm having difficulty to implement the code in the getView() method of the adapter. This is the example i'm using:[example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ThisdemoillustratestheuseofCHOICEMODEMULTIPLEMODALakaselectionmodeonGridView.htm). How can I combine this code in my getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckableLayout l;
        ImageView i;

        if (convertView == null) {
            i = new ImageView(Grid3.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));
            l = new CheckableLayout(Grid3.this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            l.addView(i);
        } else {
            l = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            i = (ImageView) l.getChildAt(0);
        }

        ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
        i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

        return l;
    }


public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        setBackgroundDrawable(checked ?
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue)
                : null);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
```

my getView() code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = convertView;

    if(convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(com.egedsoft.instaprint.R.layout.item_clickable, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(com.egedsoft.instaprint.R.id.imageClickable);
        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }


    if (!arrayUrls.get(position).getThumbnailUrl().isEmpty()){
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrayUrls.get(position).getThumbnailUrl(), holder.imgPhoto);
    }


    return vi;
}
```

Comment: How are you making a request for getting the JSON data? Does the source support paging?

Comment: I get the "next url" from the source in case there is more photo to load

Comment: @Siddharth Lele: I would appreciate if you can look at my edited question. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am afraid, I have never had to use a Grid View with selection. You should post another question for that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is how I fetch multiple photos in my activity. You can use parts of it for fit your logic. I use this to fetch Facebook Images from an Album. So my needs are (I am assuming) different from your needs. But again, the logic may be of use to you.

**Note:** This will be lengthy. ;-)

These are the global declarations for use through the ACtivity:

```
// HOLD THE URL TO MAKE THE API CALL TO
private String URL;

// STORE THE PAGING URL
private String pagingURL;

// FLAG FOR CURRENT PAGE
int current_page = 1;

// BOOLEAN TO CHECK IF NEW FEEDS ARE LOADING
Boolean loadingMore = true;

Boolean stopLoadingData = false;
```

This is the code block that fetches the initial set of Images:

```
private class getPhotosData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // CHANGE THE LOADING MORE STATUS TO PREVENT DUPLICATE CALLS FOR
        // MORE DATA WHILE LOADING A BATCH
        loadingMore = true;

        // SET THE INITIAL URL TO GET THE FIRST LOT OF ALBUMS
        URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + initialAlbumID
                + "/photos&access_token="
                + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken() + "?limit=10";

        try {

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

            if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String queryAlbums = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());

                JSONObject JOTemp = new JSONObject(queryAlbums);

                JSONArray JAPhotos = JOTemp.getJSONArray("data");

                // IN MY CODE, I GET THE NEXT PAGE LINK HERE

                getPhotos photos;

                for (int i = 0; i < JAPhotos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JOPhotos = JAPhotos.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Log.e("INDIVIDUAL ALBUMS", JOPhotos.toString());

                    if (JOPhotos.has("link")) {

                        photos = new getPhotos();

                        // GET THE ALBUM ID
                        if (JOPhotos.has("id")) {
                            photos.setPhotoID(JOPhotos.getString("id"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoID(null);
                        }

                        // GET THE ALBUM NAME
                        if (JOPhotos.has("name")) {
                            photos.setPhotoName(JOPhotos.getString("name"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoName(null);
                        }

                        // GET THE ALBUM COVER PHOTO
                        if (JOPhotos.has("picture")) {
                            photos.setPhotoPicture(JOPhotos
                                    .getString("picture"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoPicture(null);
                        }

                        // GET THE PHOTO'S SOURCE
                        if (JOPhotos.has("source")) {
                            photos.setPhotoSource(JOPhotos
                                    .getString("source"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoSource(null);
                        }

                        arrPhotos.add(photos);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // SET THE ADAPTER TO THE GRIDVIEW
        gridOfPhotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        // CHANGE THE LOADING MORE STATUS
        loadingMore = false;
    }

}
```

This is to detect when the user has scrolled to the end and fetch new set of images:

```
// ONSCROLLLISTENER
gridOfPhotos.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {

            if (stopLoadingData == false) {
                // FETCH THE NEXT BATCH OF FEEDS
                new loadMorePhotos().execute();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

And finally, this is how I fetch the next set of images:

```
private class loadMorePhotos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // SET LOADING MORE "TRUE"
        loadingMore = true;

        // INCREMENT CURRENT PAGE
        current_page += 1;

        // Next page request
        URL = pagingURL;

        try {

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

            if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String queryAlbums = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                // Log.e("PAGED RESULT", queryAlbums);

                JSONObject JOTemp = new JSONObject(queryAlbums);

                JSONArray JAPhotos = JOTemp.getJSONArray("data");

                // IN MY CODE, I GET THE NEXT PAGE LINK HERE

                getPhotos photos;

                for (int i = 0; i < JAPhotos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JOPhotos = JAPhotos.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Log.e("INDIVIDUAL ALBUMS", JOPhotos.toString());

                    if (JOPhotos.has("link")) {

                        photos = new getPhotos();

                        // GET THE ALBUM ID
                        if (JOPhotos.has("id")) {
                            photos.setPhotoID(JOPhotos.getString("id"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoID(null);
                        }

                        // GET THE ALBUM NAME
                        if (JOPhotos.has("name")) {
                            photos.setPhotoName(JOPhotos.getString("name"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoName(null);
                        }

                        // GET THE ALBUM COVER PHOTO
                        if (JOPhotos.has("picture")) {
                            photos.setPhotoPicture(JOPhotos
                                    .getString("picture"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoPicture(null);
                        }

                        // GET THE ALBUM'S PHOTO COUNT
                        if (JOPhotos.has("source")) {
                            photos.setPhotoSource(JOPhotos
                                    .getString("source"));
                        } else {
                            photos.setPhotoSource(null);
                        }

                        arrPhotos.add(photos);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
        int currentPosition = gridOfPhotos.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        // APPEND NEW DATA TO THE ARRAYLIST AND SET THE ADAPTER TO THE
        // LISTVIEW
        adapter = new PhotosAdapter(Photos.this, arrPhotos);
        gridOfPhotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setting new scroll position
        gridOfPhotos.setSelection(currentPosition + 1);

        // SET LOADINGMORE "FALSE" AFTER ADDING NEW FEEDS TO THE EXISTING
        // LIST
        loadingMore = false;
    }

}
```

And this is the helper class to `SET` and `GET` the data collected from the queries above:

```
public class getPhotos {

    String PhotoID;

    String PhotoName;

    String PhotoPicture;

    String PhotoSource;

    // SET THE PHOTO ID
    public void setPhotoID(String PhotoID)  {
        this.PhotoID = PhotoID;
    }

    // GET THE PHOTO ID
    public String getPhotoID()  {
        return PhotoID;
    }

    // SET THE PHOTO NAME
    public void setPhotoName(String PhotoName)  {
        this.PhotoName = PhotoName;
    }

    // GET THE PHOTO NAME
    public String getPhotoName()    {
        return PhotoName;
    }

    // SET THE PHOTO PICTURE
    public void setPhotoPicture(String PhotoPicture)    {
        this.PhotoPicture = PhotoPicture;
    }

    // GET THE PHOTO PICTURE
    public String getPhotoPicture() {
        return PhotoPicture;
    }

    // SET THE PHOTO SOURCE
    public void setPhotoSource(String PhotoSource)  {
        this.PhotoSource = PhotoSource;
    }

    // GET THE PHOTO SOURCE
    public String getPhotoSource()  {
        return PhotoSource;
    }
}
```

If you also want the `adapter` code, let me know. I use [Fedor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor) [Lazy Loading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) method in the adapter.

Phew. Hope any of this helps. If you have further question, feel free to ask. :-)

EDIT: Adapter code added:

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;

    ArrayList<getPhotos> arrayPhotos;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public PhotosAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<getPhotos> arrPhotos) {

        activity = a;

        arrayPhotos = arrPhotos;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayPhotos.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayPhotos.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            vi.setTag(holder);
          } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }


        if (arrayPhotos.get(position).getPhotoPicture() != null){
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrayPhotos.get(position).getPhotoPicture(), holder.imgPhoto);
        }
        return vi;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgPhoto;

    }
}
```

EDIT: Added steps to show Progress while loading:

Add a ProgressBar to you XML where you have the GridView right below it. Play around with the weight if it causes any problems.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlaProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Java, declare the `Linearlayout linlaProgressBar` as Global and cast it in the `onCreate()` and set it's visibility as `linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

And in the `onPreExecute()` use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // SHOW THE BOTTOM PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) WHILE LOADING MORE PHOTOS
    linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And finally add, this in the `onPostExecute()`

```
// HIDE THE BOTTOM PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) AFTER LOADING MORE ALBUMS
linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need! I will try it now. I appreciate if you can post the adapter code as well. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working great. Do you know if there is any possibility to add a little loading sign at the bottom of the grid? (for times loading is taking few moments)

Comment: Give me about an hour to get to my office.

Comment: @user1787773: Check the edit. This will give you a Progress Bar (Spinner) at the bottom while loading the data.

Comment: @user1787773: Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele : I'm trying to achieve something similar to this, except that currently i'm loading the images from the resource file and not an url. Could you please tell me how i can go about that. And, i'm also not sure where the getPhotosData class is called.

Comment: @jasdmystery: Here is a good tutorial that explains how to create an Array of Images from your `res` folder: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listing-images-in-gridview-using-simple-adapter-in-android/. The `getPhotos` is a pretty standard Setter / Getter class file.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Thanks for that tutorial. I've already got that bit working. What I need I need is to load is 20 images at a time in grid view and at the end of the scroll , show the spinner and load another 20 more images and so forth. But the images need to be loaded from the res folder. 

I wanted also wanted to know whether getPhotosData class (which extends the AsyncTask) is called in the main activity.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @jasdmystery: Oh my bad. I misread your earlier comment. Yes. Both the `getPhotosData` and the `loadMorePhotos` classes are in the Activity. The `loadMorePhotos` is called only when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page which is taken care of in the `setOnScrollListener` defined in the `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still working on on it. Hope I can get back in case of further clarifications.

Comment: @SiddharthLele: Could you please post `ImageLoader` code too??

Comment: @vikalpPatel: the imageloader is the lazy loader library. You will find a link to that right above the adapter code.

Comment: @SiddharthLele okay got `ImageLoader`. But when i try to run the code `https:\\graph.facebook.com\` returns me null data. Applying same querying on `Graph Api Explorer` returns me correct data.If u few secs then take a look in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861003/facebook-server-returns-null-data-on-query-querying-the-same-on-graph-api-explo

Comment: @VikalpPatel: Are you still facing a problem in that? There is a solution already market.

Comment: @SiddharthLele yeah. Can you point me in right direction by redirecting to somewhere??

Comment: Many of this functions are depreciated in 4.2, Can anyone please update this code or does any one know any lib. that help load album from Facebook?

Comment: May I ask what "arrPhotos" is? is it an ArrayList defined somewhere in your activity?

Comment: @Jack: Correct. `arrPhotos` is globally defined as: `ArrayList<getPhotos> arrPhotos` in which `getPhotos` is the POJO class used to SET and GET to handle the various data returned. I kept a few things out to keep the post as short as possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) also, are you calling "getPhotosData" in the onCreate on your activity? because I realized after finishing all the classes and code you provide it is not called anywhere.

Comment: @Jack: That is correct too ;-). `getPhotosData`is indeed called in the `onCreate()` with this: `new getPhotosData().execute();` Sorry for making you guess. I will update the post with a few other things as soon as I remember where I have stored the source (it's quite old now :-))

Comment: Thanks :) I am also trying to get the user's photos with the FB SDK like you are in this code, But I am running into an issue where I get NullPointerException in the adapter class on getCount. I am not sure why I am getting it. For the URL I am using
   URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + "me/albums"
     + "/photos&access_token=" + s.getAccessToken()
     + "?limit=10";

Comment: So that should give me the users albums, but that is the only reason I can think of as to why I am getting NPE in the adapter on getCount :(

Comment: I have posted a full question to make it easier for you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506822/npe-getcount-in-adapter-when-trying-to-get-user-albums-using-fb-sdk

Comment: Truly a day-saver..@IceMAN Thanks a ton  for this answer!! :)

Comment: I am getting more `visibleItemCount` than the number of items actually being displayed.

Comment: @Iqbal: Post it as a different question. This answer does not really deal with it. Comment with the link to your question and I'll see if I can help out. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can, take a look to [Using adapter Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) and [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) from Android Documentation.
The most important thing is that the adapter call the method `getView` passing only the position of the entries showing on screen, and asking for different positions when user scrolls.

The easy way to do is download the required image on the `getView` method of your adapter with and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

There is an [example](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

Talking from experience, it's tricky to achieve smooth scrolling (and overall responsiveness) while consuming memory reasonably.

It would be a good idea to look for existing solutions first, e.g., start here:
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

We ended up with a custom proprietary solution. It is a background thread that queues download requests and downloads and caches on the external storage only the images that are still visible. When a new image arrives, the view gets notified and decides when to notify the adapter to update.

It also saves the bandwidth, which was important in some cases.

Comment: Is there code i can look at anywhere to implement what you guys implemented? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found **IceMAN's** answer very useful, but I also recommend avoid using two AsyncTasks and you can make this easily.

You need to create a universal method to fetch needed data, where you can make an if/else condition (as an example):

```
        movies = fetchMovie.execute(sort).get();
        if (movies == null) {
            movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else if (addMovies) {
            movieList.addAll(movies);
        } else {
            movieList = movies;
        }
```

**addMovies** is a boolean in your onScroll method.
In AsyncTask provide current page in query URL and voila - you made your code smaller :)