# Grid of thumbnail images in Android

Tags: android, json, gridview

I'm creating a mini project that reads a JSON file from Flickr and get's a collection of images. I want to read those images a dispose them in a grid of images. When a user click/tap in one photo a new activity shows it in full screen.

As a bonus I want a share button on the full screen activity and loading widget on the main widget (while loading images from web).

I am beginner in Android but by now I have a JSON parser working, the next step I want to do is the grid display. So my question is, has anybody implemented something like that here? How can I do the grid trick? Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: A GridView will do the trick.<br>
Use this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) for a simple one.<br>
Or use [this one](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) if you want to deal with memory problems.

Comment: Refer this example: [Android – Select multiple photos from Gallery](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/), in this example code you can change logic of loading images from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer of mine a few days ago. It is mighty length, so instead of adding the entire code, I am merely linking to it.

You will have to adapt a few things to suit your specific needs, but there, you will find almost the entire solution to your needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265776/450534.

I make use of [Fedor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor) [Lazy Loading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList), but feel free to use the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) as suggested by *Lazy Ninja*

Comment: That for sure will help me with this mini project! The next step is Facebook connectivity. Now i'm going to get hands dirty and implement this first! Thanks you @Siddharth!