# ProgressBar at the bottom of gridview

Tags: android, gridview, progress-bar

I have a GridView which shows a grid of 15 Views for the first time. Then, on click of a button, I add 5 more grid views. So, my question is:  How to add a ProgressBar at the bottom of a page, when those 5 Views are loading ? Like a spinner loading and the 5 Views get updated.

Hi i have a tab host tabwidget for tabs and gridview inside framlayout..now if i want the progressbar then should i need to inclue this linearlayout after frame layout or inside frame laoyout?

Answer (score 1):

Add this below your `GridView` in the XML.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlaProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your `Activity`, where you are loading the data (assuming, it is an `AsyncTask`), in your `onPreExecute()` show it:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // SHOW THE BOTTOM PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) WHILE LOADING MORE PHOTOS
    linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And in the `onPostExecute()`, hide it:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    // SHOW THE BOTTOM PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) WHILE LOADING MORE PHOTOS
    linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

If you are not using an `AsyncTask`, then set the visibility to `View.VISIBLE` at the start of the method where you start downloading the data and set it to `View.GONE` either after or just before you set the `Adapter`.

**EDIT:** Adding additional info.

Couple of things.

1. You are downloading data off the Internet for which, I would recommend switching to `AsycnTask` instead of using a conventional `() Method`.
2. Check out my answer a few days ago on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265776/450534

In that answer, you will find a complete solution that will suit your exact needs. Well, almost entirely anyway. You may have to make a few modifications and adapt to a few things yourself. But by and large, it will answer all your questions. I use it in my apps and they function as you say, the Google Play *loading* text at the bottom. And it really is complete. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ..it worked ..but one thing i need is that this linearlayout must be attached to the gridview ..like as he scrolls up this should be attached with loading symbol and then should disappear..

Comment: @user1340801: It will keep displaying as long as the data is loading. Once it is done, the `View.GONE` will make hide it.

Comment: i understood it..i need it ti be attached to the griview above..like they have in google play when you scroll a gridview you have a layout consisting of progressbar attached with loading..

Comment: @user1340801: So a _loading..._ with the spinning progress when you scroll to the bottom right?

Comment: Are you using an `AsyncTask` to perform the functions?

Comment: Sure. But how are you running the functions to download the data? Is it a conventional `() Method` or in an `AsyncTask`? And also, are you calling a different method to get the next 5 data set when you click the button?

Comment: its a conventional ()Method where iam parsing the xml after executin a url ..nope im calling the same method when for the next 5 data but change in url..

Comment: @user1340801: Check my edit. I have linked to a complete solution using `AsyncTask` from one of my answers earlier. It will address all your questions.

Comment: Hi i have a tab host tabwidget for tabs and gridview inside framlayout..now if i want the progressbar then should i need to inclue this linearlayout after frame layout or inside frame laoyout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom view for that and inflate it and add as bottom view in gridview

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<Button android:text="Load"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>          

<ProgressBar 
       android:layout_width="25.0dip"
       android:layout_height="25.0dip"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:visibility="gone"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now inflate this view and show the progressbar at bottom of gridview
You can set button as bottom with this when you click just visible the progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `ProgressBar` in your layout, set its visibility to `VISIBLE` or `GONE` whenever you want to show/hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a  in the xml of GridView and set its property "alignParentRight = true" and "visibility = invisible" . In your activity , use Async task class and on its preExectue method set set its visibility to visible

`pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

In doInBackground method load your images and finally in onPostExecute method make this progress bar invisible.

```
pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

execute this async task class on click of load button.

This is an easy tutorial for understanding asyncTask

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Or threads can be used instead of async task.

Comment: set adapter in the postExecute method. progressBar visibility and invisibility wont work without async task or threading. You can not make it visible or invisible in a single thread.