# How to get all the pics from the facebook album using fbsdk 3.0 in android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all the image from the images from my facebook album.And i give the read permissions "email,user_photos,friends". I m getting all the users albums.but when i try to get album's pics then response contain only first image of album with different dimensions.I m sending facebook Graph request as "albumID/photos". 
code for sending Request :

Request req = new Request(session, albumId+"/photos", null, HttpMethod.GET,callback);

Please anyone tell me how to get all pics from facebook album.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u seen this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718651/android-facebook-album-photos-request-only-returns-25-photos][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718651/android-facebook-album-photos-request-only-returns-25-photos

Answer (score 0):

See my question, I have solved that problem:
[android how to obtain "any valid access_token" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993300/android-how-to-obtain-any-valid-access-token-in-android)

use this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/run-fql-queries/