# android how to obtain "any valid access_token" in android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In order to get the aid of the albums (or other fields in this field) in the official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album says that I need:

- **any valid access_token if it is public.**

  user_photos permissions if it is not public and belongs to the user.

  friends_photos permissions if it is not public and belongs to a user's friend.

I don't get the info I need from the album field when I use "SELECT aid from album WHERE owner = me()". 
The permissions I have added in my android app, but:
 1.-How do I get that valid acces_token in android?
2.-what is exactly that valid acces_token the document specified?  
3.-if you can please provide a sample of code.

**Edit, the solution:**
I have solved my problem, and apparently the valid access_token is used automatically when you start a query, also my query is: `SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner = me() AND aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me())`

The token is a long-term and will expire during 60  days and to get another one, simply log out and log in again and you will get a new one.

Finally this is my permissions:

```
"user_likes", "user_status", "friends_birthday",
                "friends_location",
                "friends_relationship_details","friends_relationships",
                "user_photos","friends_photos","user_friends",
                "email"
```

Hope this help others in the future.

Comment: it may be helpful ..acesstoken=session.getAccessToken();

Comment: I have used that, but I'm not sure how I can add it in my code,Do you have an idea how to implement that in the query SELECT aid from album WHERE owner = me() ?? or in which part of the code should be used? thanks

Comment: may i know what are you accesing from the fb. friends list or any other?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you, but I'm trying to get the aid from the album field when I have already his/her id taken from a previous successful query from the album user.

Answer (score 1):

to get access for friends album..and else this link helps you
[facebook by github](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)

also asked in [How to get all the pics from the facebook album using fbsdk 3.0 in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893392/how-to-get-all-the-pics-from-the-facebook-album-using-fbsdk-3-0-in-android)

Comment: let me give it a try, looks interesting, I will back eventually comment the results, and thanks.

Comment: I have solved, see my question again, the email permission was missing, and thanks