# Some details about displaying images on an Android phone that are hosted on the internet

Tags: android

I was trying to find ways to show images on an android devices that are stored on the internet, and I came across these tutorials:

http://www.androidcookers.blogspot.com/2011/06/retrieve-image-from-internet.html
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/downloading-an-image-from-the-server-and-displaying-it-on-screen/

Now my app will be sort of a gallery like application where there will be multiple images that must be displayed to the user from the internet.

From the methods pointed to above, I gather that the image will somewhere be downloaded on the phone first and then displayed on the app.

Since I'm dealing with multiple images, I'd like to know, where are these images stored? And after the app closes, do I need to take care of some kind of cleanup where I delete the images I downloaded, or something like that? And is there any restriction on the amount of space that my application can consume while downloading these images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest under the circumstances is using a LazyLoader. There are a couple of very popular *libraries* available. One is [Fedor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor) [Lazy Loading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) and the other is the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

> Now my app will be sort of a gallery like application where there will
>   be multiple images that must be displayed to the user from the
>   internet.

For that, I would recommend using a `GridView`. For a complete working solution, you can refer to a post of mine that makes use of a `GridView` to display the images in (it is very lengthy and hence a link to the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265776/450534

**NOTE:** *In the example linked to, I am pulling information from using Facebook API, but you can always extract / extrapolate the essence of the code to suit your exact need. Naturally, you will need to adapt certain parts and fit in your own logic, but it will be enough to get you started.*

In the answer linked to, I use *Fedor's* Lazy Loader.

> Since I'm dealing with multiple images, I'd like to know, where are
>   these images stored? And after the app closes, do I need to take care
>   of some kind of cleanup where I delete the images I downloaded, or
>   something like that? And is there any restriction on the amount of
>   space that my application can consume while downloading these images?

With either of the Lazy Loader or the Universal Image Loader, you will not have to worry about it. The idea is to cache the Images that are downloaded. The *Lazy Loader* checks for images already cached and uses them instead of downloading the Image all over again. They can be stored in a folder of your choice by simply changing the path. In one of my applications which uses Lazy Loader, I have the option of clearing the cache from the Settings panel. Plus, the folder itself, can be manually deleted using a File Explorer.

Comment: I will look into it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

They're stored wherever you tell them to store-  generally either in your apps private directory on internal storage or on external storage.  If you're going to use the images again, keep them so you don't need to download them again next time.  If you aren't, you should delete them.  There are space restrictions on internal storage but the exact amount is determined by your phone model.  External storage is limited only by the size of the sd card.