# Facebook server returns null data on query. Querying the same on Graph API Explorer gives me correct JSON Data

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to fetch the photos from particular album on facebook. Trying below `URL` gives me perfect data when querying at `Graph API Explorer`. But it returns null in my application code.

Also when I tried on browser it returns me:

```
{
 "data": { 
    ]
 }
```

which basically `null`:

URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/3386086936429/photos?limit=10";

```
try {
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

String st=rp.toString();

Log.e("RESPONSE", st);
Log.e("ACCESS_TOKEN",at);

if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
       String queryAlbums = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());

       int s=rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
       String a=String.valueOf(s);
       Log.e("RESPONSE-IF", a);

       JSONObject JOTemp = new JSONObject(queryAlbums);

       JSONArray JAPhotos = JOTemp.getJSONArray("data");

      Log.e("JSONArray", String.valueOf(JAPhotos));
      Log.e("JSONArray-Length",String.valueOf(JAPhotos.length()));
```

Log:

```
02-14 00:12:34.280: E/RESPONSE(1320)org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40518ac8
02-14 00:12:34.301: E/RESPONSE-IF(1320): 200
02-14 00:12:34.310: E/JSONArray(1320): []
02-14 00:12:34.310: E/JSONArray-Length(1320): 0
```

Where am I going wrong while querying?

Comment: I am getting same error while using pagination. can you help me by providing how you solve this issue?

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya you can catch up in detail about the fix as it got resolved in the file @ https://github.com/vikalppatelce/PostCardAviaryFb/blob/master/PostCardAviaryFb/src/com/orangesoft/postcardaviary/fb/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to visit your ID on Facebook or query it via the Graph API, I get a "Unsupported get request" error. That tells me that either you've got the wrong id, or this id has restrictions on who can view it.

If you are able to view this information, then you can only get this information if you have an access token from a user who meets that object's restrictions.

Comment: So whatever i'm querying is right?? Cause https://graph.facebook.com/3386086936429/photos?limit=10" querying on Graph Api Explorer gives me correct data. Querying on browser or Application returns empty data.

Comment: This object must have restrictions. I can't see it in either the explorer or within Facebook. (I'm in the USA). When you're using the Graph API Explorer, it gets your user access token. You must personally pass the restrictions. So, to get this object's data you must have a user access token from a user that meets the restrictions. According to the TOS, you can't cache this token and show this data to a user that doesn't pass (like me).