# EnldlessAdapter for GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

Could anyone suggest how to show "loading" view when gridview reached the end and need to load another chunk of data using one of the existing endless adapter libraries or custom impementation?

The main problem here is to add view to fill the space across all the columns at the bottom row which seems not to be possible in GridView.

Comment: I have an entire working solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13265776/450534. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, could you post your link in a separate answer so that I can accept it in cause it would be the best?

Comment: But did it help? No point if it did not work for you eh? ;-)

Comment: Still had no time to try it, sorry. But huge thanks anyway. Leave your answer as separate post and you will know :)

Comment: Lol... Take your time fella. Let me know if and when it works. I am more curious about that. :-)

Comment: Okay, I will, huge thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have posted an answer which integrates pagination for an Endless Scrolling List here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265776/450534

It is too big to post all over again, so am linking to the original answer instead.

Comment: Downvoted. The author clearly asks how to implement a `GridView` with a loading footer. Something your solution never does.

Comment: @AlaksiejN.: Appreciate the comment. But perhaps, **you** should read the question and the solution linked to more carefully. The solution **IS** for a `GridView`.

Comment: Your solution just shows a progress bar below `GridView` and is not part of the gridview. It can be thought of as a workaround for what author asked, but not the exact solution, since you don't add a `load more` footer to the `GridView` which is part of it, i.e. scrolls together with the rest of the items.