# adding button to a gridview in android

Tags: android

I know that it may be a silly question...but I'm new to android...I have an gridview layout in my project and I used "android developer" code for writing the code...so the xml code of layout is like this :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

now I want to add a button to the gridview but I can't do it with drag and drop...I've tried to write the xml code of adding button but I've got this error :
"Error in an XML file: aborting build."
can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Do you want a button in each cell, or above it, below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Button` to be **below** the `GridView`, use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridFriends"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnDemo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" >
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want a `Button` in every cell in the `GridView`, you will have to use a Custom `GridView` that uses an Adapter. An exmaple XML snippet for the custom cell in the `GridView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnDemo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" >
        </ImageButton>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE:** In the XMLS snippets in the post, I am using `ImageButton's`. Change them and any necessary attributes to that of a `Button`. It is merely an *illustration*. You should be able to connect the dots though. ;-)

if you are familiar with the concept of custom `ListViews`, with a few modifications, you will be able to implement a custom `GridView` too. If you are not familiar with custom `ListViews` or `GridViews`, follow this tutorial to see how to create a custom `GridView`: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/29/custom-gridview-in-android-a-simple-example/.

Or use this [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+custom+gridview+example&oq=android+custom+gridview&gs_l=hp.3.1.0j0i7j0l2.67.6157.0.7796.23.23.0.0.0.6.474.4796.0j14j5j2j2.23.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.mQ3YMh3tzDI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.bmk&fp=aa8f2157e742c828&biw=1440&bih=775) for more tutorials on custom `GridView's`.

And [this is a link to an answer of mine on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265776/450534). It has the complete solution. Use what logic suits your purpose.

Comment: @eng.m.a: I am glad it was. :-)