# Dynamically add more cards in a list Row android TV leanback

Tags: android, json, android-tv, leanback

I am working on a Android TV app for quite some time now and I have come far while working on it. I am trying to develop an app like popcorn time but it's for Google nexus TV box.
The problem where I am stuck in, is really simple but even after a lot of effort I am still unable to figure out the solution.
I am fetching the json data from my database which has all the movies details and links and this works perfectly fine.
[Over all app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muSk9.jpg)

Now those who have used the you tube app on Android TV must have noticed that it was built on leanback and as you scroll down in a listrow more cards are added into a row and likewise the app made the json calls to fetch more data according to the category we are scrolling in. (that's what I want to do)

Right now it is impossible, if I request for large data it takes a long time to fetch everything from the server so I have devised a way via which I can make json calls on scroll but I am unable to present them in a listrow at runtime.

Comment: Post your adapter code.! where you add json values to the adapter and the adapter to the listrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with android TV Leanback library from past 7 or 8 months. And I have developed my own presenter class via which you can load more cards dynamically on scroll, but its not possible using Leanback Library, ListAdapter updateds a single row and than move to next category to update it's cards. which take time on run time.

I have used the below answer to create my own presenter class. The Trick while implementing endless loading on scroll is that you have to create two AysncTasks.

Have a look at at post 34

[Lazy download images into gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265457/lazy-download-images-into-gridview)

it will a little time taking but you will get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

To add items to a presenter;

```
CardPresenter channelCardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
ArrayObjectAdapter channelRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(channelCardPresenter);
channelRowAdapter.add(new Movie("Movie Title"));
HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(0, "My Channels");
mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, channelRowAdapter));
```

Of course this may only work for the first time you're creating the UI. Future times may not do this. In my app, https://github.com/Fleker/CumulusTV/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/felkertech/n/tv/LeanbackFragment.java, I create a method that will be called each time I want to do a full redraw of the app:

```
public void refreshUI() {
    prepareBackgroundManager();
    setupUIElements();
    loadRows(); //Generate and populate all the rows
    setupEventListeners();
}
```