# android tv -Reloading adapter data

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I want to re-load some of the rows data in a browse fragment.

Basically I want to reset the adapter data without causing a flash like effect in the browse fragment. Any idea how it can be done?

Something like `notifyDataSetChanged()` in list view.

Thanx

Comment: just add the values to the adapter using adapter.add(item). incase you are adding to existing values or do adapter.clear() and the add.

Answer (score 5):

This will refresh data without losing current position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.size(); i++) {
    ListRow listRow = ((ListRow) mAdapter.get(i));
    ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = ((ArrayObjectAdapter) listRow.getAdapter());
    if (listRowAdapter.size() > 0) {
        listRowAdapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(0, listRowAdapter.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar in this question:
[Dynamically add more cards in a list Row android TV leanback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842404/dynamically-add-more-cards-in-a-list-row-android-tv-leanback)

I'll copy my answer from there. Hopefully this helps.

To add items to a presenter;

```
CardPresenter channelCardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
ArrayObjectAdapter channelRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(channelCardPresenter);
channelRowAdapter.add(new Movie("Movie Title"));
HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(0, "My Channels");
mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, channelRowAdapter));
```

Of course this may only work for the first time you're creating the UI. Future times may not do this. In my app, [CumulusTV](https://github.com/Fleker/CumulusTV/blob/e85b7aa153fcd7bb5d1b23127a8002f3a8204120/app/src/main/java/com/felkertech/n/tv/LeanbackFragment.java), I create a method that will be called each time I want to do a full redraw of the app:

```
public void refreshUI() {
    prepareBackgroundManager();
    setupUIElements();
    loadRows(); //Generate and populate all the rows
    setupEventListeners();
}
```

Comment: your link is broken, can you please post it again?

Comment: I have made many changes to the codebase since I originally posted the answer. I went back through the commit history and updated the URL to point to the file at the time of answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own adapter and add a new replaceAll() method.

```
public void replaceAll(Collection items){
 int itemsCount = items.size();
 if (itemsCount == 0){
    return;
 }
 mItems.clear();
 mItems.addAll(index, items);
 notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemsCount);
}
```

complete source:[link](https://medium.com/@be.betr.codr/how-to-refresh-the-android-tv-browsefragment-6e4d2d3c6690#.kjwu8quv6)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my kotlin version of @ewilly's answer, implementing only `replaceAll` which I use to both initially populate and incrementally update the list.

```
class RefreshableArrayObjectAdapter(presenter: Presenter): ObjectAdapter(presenter) {
    var items: ArrayList<Any> = arrayListOf()

    override fun isImmediateNotifySupported(): Boolean = true

    override fun size(): Int = items.size

    override fun get(position: Int): Any = items[position]

    fun replaceAll(list: Collection<Any>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(0, list)
        notifyChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
 * Notify that the content of a range of items changed. Note that this is
 * not same as items being added or removed.
 *
 * @param positionStart The position of first item that has changed.
 * @param itemCount The count of how many items have changed.
 */
public void notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
}
```

Notify that the content of a range of items changed. Note that this is
 * not same as items being added or removed.

if you want add or remove item,please try [this](https://medium.com/@be.betr.codr/how-to-refresh-the-android-tv-browsefragment-6e4d2d3c6690):

```
1.mRowsAdapter.clear();
2.mRowsApdapter.addAll();
```