# Android, can i update Grid view without using notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

Android App. has custom product GridView (ProductImage/ProductPrice/ProductDiscount).. every time user scroll down the App. fetch new products and updating GridView using notifyDataSetChanged(). - 
the problem is when updating GridView with new products, the scroll return to top of GridView which force user to scroll down again from the beginning of the GridView. **Is there anyway can use to update GridView rather notifyDataSetChanged to stop updating the whole GridView?**

Comment: Have you tried this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265457/lazy-download-images-into-gridview/13265776#13265776

Comment: what exactly do you want to update?

Comment: @AshishTiwari , yes i tried but i lost and didn't find what i want.

Comment: @Shahar ,i fetch 3 products at time and when scroll reached bottom the Asynctask  fetches new 3 products and redraw the GridView to show 6 products now, what i want that scroll stay at the same postion at middle of GridView and not moved to the start of GridView, show new products into GridView without redrawing the whole GridView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using RecyclerView like Vogella is showing [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

than you can add items and use on of those

```
    RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position);
    RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemInserted(int position);
    RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int positionEnd);
    RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int positionEnd);
```