# on press back girdView should come back on the same position while infinite Scrolling

Tags: java, android

I am facing the issue while using girdView that while creating a simple gallery app, when i scroll down and open an image and back to previous activity
there are two behaviour:
1- if i had written onPressBack function, it reload the girdView and it start from start even if i were on last Image
2- if i don't write onPressBack function, it back to current position but if delete the image, the image remain in the gird...
this is the whole issue i am new in android your help will be great favour thanks

Comment: Hi , can you shared the code ? it will help more to understand what is wrong ,Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for RecyclerView with Gridview manager, try this [Android, can i update Grid view without using notifyDataSetChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999751/android-can-i-update-grid-view-without-using-notifydatasetchanged)