# How to load Gridview images on scroll faster

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing an social media app. Basically this is a photo sharing app. I am loading images in **GridView** and everything working fine except `image loading speed`. Speed is decreased because it is loading all images at same time. How can i load only few images first then it will load more on `scroll`?.
What I want More likely is getting e.g, 10 images at first time and so on after scrolling each time and get more images untill all are loaded.

**MyGridAdapter**

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<ImageObject> imageObjects;

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflate;


public MyGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageObject> imageObjects) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageObjects = imageObjects;

    this.mLayoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    if (imageObjects != null) return imageObjects.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position)
        return imageObjects.get(position);

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position)
        return imageObjects.get(position).getId();

    return 0;
}
public String getImageId(int position){
    if (imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position)
        return imageObjects.get(position).getImageid();
    return null;
}
public String getUsername(int position){
    if (imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position)
        return imageObjects.get(position).getUsername();
    return null;
}
public String getCaption(int position){
    if (imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position)
        return imageObjects.get(position).getCaption();
    return null;
}

public String getProfilePic(int position){
    if (imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position)
        return imageObjects.get(position).getProfilepic();
    return null;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mLayoutInflate.inflate(R.layout.imageitem, parent,
                false);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ImageObject imageObject = (ImageObject) getItem(position);
    if (imageObject != null) {
        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(imageObject.getImageUrl())
                .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_load_anim)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .crossFade()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(viewHolder.imageView);
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: add pagination to your recyclerview.

Comment: Have you tried using lazy loading?'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy download images into gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265457/lazy-download-images-into-gridview)

Comment: Yeah read about that but didnt get it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have suffered a lot from this problem, but here is a really Goode solution.

You can use this library which is called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

This is how you have to use

**Add this to your Gradel file**

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

**And this is how you load and set the Image to a GridView**

```
GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(path/url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

This is a really excellent library. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I am already using using it. My question is about load only 10-12 images first then load other images on scroll.

Comment: @AjayGohel You can try using the newer version. I think it has a better management of all these issues.

Comment: @AjayGohel But in case you are upgrading to the newer version to keep the backup of the app's project files.