# How to get list of Albums from Facebook via Graph API?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

It's about 3 hours that I'm searching but didn't find solution!

When my application launches, I ask user to accept some permissions that I need like [user_photos and friends_photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/).

I want to show user's album, somewhere in application. I'm using following url in order to load the list:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID/albums&access_token=TOKEN
```

I have no idea why response (by Facebook) is:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/albums&access_token=CAAERueNZBUuoBABxodZCJsriyKui9ji4ZCz4JCfICF8Le91reds2aA09KAB7EFGjoM2ypeObJfQYgUbkwNVFW55irH1ITX68vMTO833pSIv2M3dCJZCZB1eHoaz1ZCjs9lIZB0KDZCR0e0NTVlZA7WZBt8fWTmIAZC0hTAy6BZC8FMbUKvdDCJ5Rg4KqS2m0Tp5p9E38IwnRt7Sv6ySLT74GimYsIP4mmCTcIEspNCJPtoIZAHQZDRT","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Seems some people are doing same way but they have no problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385652/513413).
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

========

**UPDATE**

I just tested following url `https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums&access_token=TOKEN` and the result was

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, stupid mistake!

First parameter of URL starts with "?" instead of "&".
So, after changing the url to `https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID/albums?access_token=TOKEN`, it's working :)